# scala cloud foundry mongodb : access to mongodb denied

Tags: scala, mongodb, cloud-foundry

I have installed eclipse, the cloudfoundry plugin, the scala plugin,the vaadin plugin(for web developments) and the mongodb libraries.

I created a class like this :

```
import vaadin.scala.Application
import vaadin.scala.VerticalLayout
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoConnection
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject
import vaadin.scala.Label
import vaadin.scala.Button

class Launcher extends Application {

   val label=new Label

   override def main = new VerticalLayout() {

      val coll=MongoConnection()("mybd")("somecollection")

      val builder=MongoDBObject.newBuilder
      builder+="foo1" -> "bar"
      var newobj=builder.result()
      coll.save(newobj)

      val mongoColl=MongoConnection()("mybd")("somecollection")

      val withFoo=mongoColl.findOne()

      label.value=withFoo
      add(label)

      //bouton pour faire joli
      add(new Button{
        caption_=("click me!")
      })
   }
}
```

the error (the access to the mongodb database is denied) comes from the parameters, which are the default ones.
do you know how to set up the good parameters in scala or in java?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got some help on the [vcap-dev](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/d/msg/vcap-dev/bVdoc1-d1oE/b8wMT9poHV4J) mailing list

```
package com.example.vaadin_1

import vaadin.scala.Application
import org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.CloudEnvironment
import org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.MongoServiceInfo
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoConnection


class Launcher extends Application {

   val cloudEnvironment = new CloudEnvironment()
   val mongoServices = cloudEnvironment.getServiceInfos(classOf[MongoServiceInfo])
   val mongo = mongoServices.get(0)
   val mongodb = MongoConnection(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort())("abc")
   mongodb.authenticate(mongo.getUserName(),mongo.getPassword())           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do it using [Spring Data for MongoDB](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb) there is a sample application for Cloudfoundry in particular [put together by the Spring guys](https://github.com/SpringSource/cloudfoundry-samples/tree/master/hello-spring-mongodb). With a [bit of xml configuration](https://github.com/SpringSource/cloudfoundry-samples/blob/master/hello-spring-mongodb/src/main/resources/root-context.xml) you have ready to inject the mongoTemplate similar to the familiar Spring xxxTemplate paradigm.

Comment: hello
thanks for your answer, but if possible I would like to avoid spring.

Comment: it's rather strange that in the doc of cloudfoundry it is impossible to find such informations in java at least!

Answer (score 0):

when deploying to CloudFoundry, the information relative to connecting to a service (*i.e* mongo in your case) is made available to the app through environment variable `VCAP_SERVICES`. It is a json document with one entry per service. You could of course parse it yourself, but you will find the class http://cf-runtime-api.cloudfoundry.com/org/cloudfoundry/runtime/env/CloudEnvironment.html useful. You will need to add the org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-runtime/0.8.1 jar to your project. You can use it without Spring.

Have a look at http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/services.html for explanation of the VCAP_SERVICES underlying var